# How to calculate time betwen first and last connection in a Java TCP Server/Client program

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am doing a project for the university where they ask me to send messages from different clients to a server. One of the things they ask me is to calculate the time from the first time a client connects to the server and the last time. I can't think of a way to calculate this time and that's where my question comes, I'm a little new to sockets, maybe it's something simple. Appreciate your help.

Server

```
public class Reportero {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    ServerSocket servidor = null;
    Socket sc = null;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    int contador = 0;
    
    final int PUERTO = 5000;
    
     try {
        
         servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
         System.out.println("Reportero iniciado.");
         
         
         while(true) {
             
             sc = servidor.accept();
             //Cliente conectado
             
             in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
             out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
             
             String mensaje = in.readUTF();
             
             System.out.println(mensaje);
             
             out.writeUTF("Hola desde el reportero.");
             
             contador++;
             System.out.println("Cantidad de información recibida: " + contador);
             
             sc.close();
             //Cliente desconectado
         }
                     
     }catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Reportero.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     }
}
```

Client

```
public class Consumidor {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    
    final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    final int PUERTO = 5000;
    
    
    
 try {      
        DataInputStream in;
        DataOutputStream out;
        Socket sc = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
        in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        
        out.writeUTF(encryptThisString(m));
        
        //Imprimir mensaje que envía el reportero
        //System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        
        sc.close();
        
            
        }catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
        
    
    
}
}
```

This is my code, hope you can help me.

Comment: Declare two variables. Whenever `servidor.accept()` returns a new socket, save the current time to the 2nd variable, and if the 1st variable hasn't been assigned a value yet then assign the current time to that variable, too.  Then, you can simply subtract the 2 variables whenever needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you need, the time between one connection and another from the same client, or the time between connection and disconnection from a client?

Comment: @Miguel I need the time between the first connection from a client and the last disconnection from a client.

Comment: @Kempis dies it need to be the same client, or can they  be different?